# How to retrieve alias key password android keystore

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore

I have the backup keystore file and also the keystore password. Also the right key alias name. But, I think I have forgotten the key alias password. I am confirming that my keystore password and key alias name are 100% OK.

So, when I am trying to generate signed apk it says `Failed to read key`

My question is how can I recover or retrieve the key alias password?

Comment: Hi @0xAliHn, did you end up finding a solution to this problem. I am having the exact same issue at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can recover/retrieve the `key password`. You should have it stored it like you did for the keystore password.

There is a chance that you may have used the same keystore password for your key password as well. You could give that a try.

Comment: I used the same password, but unfortunately that's not working. May be somehow it has been changed, that's why I am looking for a way how to recover this to check the original password.